# Run Jmeter in non GUI Mode from Gradle Jmeter Plugin

Tags: gradle, jmeter

Context: Right now I am using jmeter gradle plugin from Kulya. But I need to generate graphical results, so I used jmeter plugins..but I need to run this using command prompt and cannot run using gradle jmeter plugin.

Earlier:

```
 jmeterRun.configure {
               srcDir = file('src/test/performance/jmeter/')
               jmeterTestFiles = [file('src/test/performance/jmeter/<MY_FILE>.jmx')]
           }
```

Now I need to run like this:

```
jmeter.bat -t <MY_FILE>.jmx -n -l /data/jmeter/concurrent/concurrent-test-results.csv
```

The problem is,I am not able to execute this command using jmeter gradle plugin.specifically pass the parameters like -n -l using jmetr gradle plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure save results file in user properties, then include the properties file in gradle config using `jmeterUserPropertiesFiles`

To start jmeter in non-gui via gradle, you use:

```
gradle jmeterRun
```

Answer (score 1):

I [created a GitHub project](https://github.com/djangofan/launch-jmeter), as a template, with all of this setup.  It is configured so that developers can launch jmeter from a Git repository and each developer thus shares the same Jmeter with the exact same capabilities/libraries.

It doesn't solve your issue of easily passing parameters, but it looks like the other suggestion of using external properties files will probably work.